# Problemas com aplicaçõe localhost com AngularJS e NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, servidor

Estou com algumas dúvidas e problemas para tentar criar um servidor com *nodeJS*.

A questão é que tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com *AngularJS* bem simples e quero fazer outra  em *nodeJS* que basicamente carrega a do *AngularJS*.

Eu criei um servidorzinho usando esse código:

```
    var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./angular-js-web-form/index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

O que ele faz é criar um servidor local lendo o arquivo `index.html`, este que é o `index` da aplicação em *angularJS*:

[image: app angular aberto]

Aparentemente funciona, porém ele não consegue importar todos os styles, todos os *js* externos, as funções e etc.

Eu sei que existem servidores para isso, como *grunt*, porém queria evita-los. Quero que minha aplicação em angular rode somente com um simples servidor como este acima.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como ajudar? Sugestão?

Desde já deixo meus agradecimentos.

### EDIÇÃO:

Acabei encontrando esse link que é mais ou menos o que eu preciso: https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/

só que ele ainda usa um modulo que é o *Express*, só é possível usando ele? Não tem como criar aplicações locais só importando o `index` e o `index` fazendo o *import* do restante?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu codigo do servidor esta funcionando em parte pois esta considerando apenas um tipo de conteudo (`"Content-Type": "text/html"`).

Tente utilizar o codigo abaixo. Utiliza apenas NodeJS e alguns do modulos que vem com NodeJS.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './index.html';

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
        case '.png':
           contentType = 'image/png';
           break;      
        case '.jpg':
           contentType = 'image/jpg';
           break;
        case '.wav':
           contentType = 'audio/wav';
           break;
}

fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
    if (error) {
        if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
            fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                response.end(content, 'utf-8');
            });
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(500);
            response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
            response.end(); 
        }
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
        response.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
});

}).listen(8000);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela sua atenção, porém, o resultado ainda é o mesmo

Comment: Estranho. Estou rodando esse codigo aqui na maquina local e o servidor funciona perfeitamente: carrega JS, CSS, Images e etc. @PauloGustavo

Comment: O que eu fiz foi copiar esse código e colocar num arquivo JS e executa-lo com o comando node readHtml.js. Será que foi a estrutura do meu projeto que está errada?

Esse file em nodeJS ta na pasta /home/paulo.s/teste e a aplicação está dentro de /home/paulo.s/teste/app. Eu mudei ali o código pra pegar o ./app/index.html.

Comment: @PauloGustavo Seguindo a estrutura que voce falou acima, depois que voce executar o comando `node readHtml.js' dentro da pasta " /home/paulo.s/teste" voce deve acessar a url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app". Assim o arquivo "app/index.html" deve carregar a sua aplicacao.

Comment: Amigo, realmente, o erro foi meu mesmo. Com esse seu ultimo comentário que me toquei fafauh. Muito obrigado!